# C++: Multithreaded merge sort witn N threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting, thread-safety, mergesort

I`m trying to write merge sort with 2 threads.
I divide array into 2 pieces and sort each half with usual merge sort. After that I just merge two sorted parts.
Usual merge sort works correctly, and if I apply it to eash part without threads, it works correctly too.

I run a lof of tests on randomly generated short arrays, and there can be 2k of correct tests, but sometimes my multithread sort doesn`t work properly.
After sorting each half but before merging them, I check them. Sometimes the set of numbers in current part of array occurs to be different from orinigal set of numbers in that part before sorting, the numbers just appear from nowhere.
There must be some problem with threads, because there is no such problem without them.

As you can see, I made **buffer with length = array.size() and I pass reference on it to functions. When merging two sorted arrays, this buffer is used.
Each buffer element is initialized with 0.**

I`m sure that there is no shared data, because every function uses separated part of buffer. The correct work of usual merge sort supports that.

Please, help to understand, what is wrong with this way of using threads, I`m absolutely confused.

P. S. my code is supposed to execute sorting in N threads, not in 2, that`s why I create array of threads. But even with 2 it doesn`t work.

```
Multithread function:
void merge_sort_multithread(std::vector<int>& arr, std::vector<int>& buffer, unsigned int threads_count)
{
    int length = arr.size();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    // dividing array into nearly equal parts
    std::vector<int> thread_from; // array with indexes of part`s start
    std::vector<int> thread_length; // array with part`s length
    make_parts(thread_from, thread_length, threads_count, length);

    // start threads
    for (int i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(merge_sort, std::ref(arr), std::ref(buffer),
                                                thread_length[i], thread_from[i]));
    }

    // waiting for end of sorting
    for (int i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
        threads[i].join();

    // ------- here I check each part and find mistakes, so next function is not important ----
    merge_sorted_after_multithreading(arr, buffer, thread_from, thread_length, threads_count, 0);
}

Usual merge sort:
void merge_sort(std::vector<int>& arr, std::vector<int>& buffer, size_t length, int from)
{
    if (length == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int length_left = length / 2;
    int length_right = length - length_left;

    // sorting each part
    merge_sort(arr, buffer, length_left, from);
    merge_sort(arr, buffer, length_right, from + length_left);

    // merging sorted parts
    merge_arrays(arr, buffer, length_left, length - length_left, from, from + length_left);
}

Merging two sorted arrays with buffer:
void merge_arrays(std::vector<int>& arr, std::vector<int>& buffer, size_t length_left, size_t length_right, int start_left, int start_right)
{
    int idx_left, idx_right, idx_buffer;
    idx_left = idx_right = idx_buffer = 0;

    while ((idx_left < length_left) && (idx_right < length_right))
    {
        if (arr[start_left + idx_left] < arr[start_right + idx_right])
        {
            do {
                buffer[idx_buffer] = arr[start_left + idx_left];
                ++idx_buffer;
                ++idx_left;
            } while ((idx_left < length_left) && (arr[start_left + idx_left] < arr[start_right + idx_right]));
        }
        else
        {
            do {
                buffer[idx_buffer] = arr[start_right + idx_right];
                ++idx_buffer;
                ++idx_right;
            } while ((idx_right < length_right) && (arr[start_right + idx_right] < arr[start_left + idx_left]));
        }
    }

    if (idx_left == length_left)
    {
        for (; idx_right < length_right; ++idx_right)
        {
            buffer[idx_buffer] = arr[start_right + idx_right];
            ++idx_buffer;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (; idx_left < length_left; ++idx_left)
        {
            buffer[idx_buffer] = arr[start_left + idx_left];
            ++idx_buffer;
        }
    }

    // copying result to original array
    for (int i = 0; i < idx_buffer; ++i)
    {
        arr[start_left + i] = buffer[i];
    }
}

Dividing array into separated parts:
void make_parts(std::vector<int>& thread_from, std::vector<int>& thread_length, unsigned int threads_count, size_t length)
{
    int dlength = (length / threads_count);
    int odd_length = length % threads_count;
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
    {
        if (odd_length > 0)
        {
            thread_length.push_back(dlength + 1);
            --odd_length;
        }
        else
            thread_length.push_back(dlength);

        thread_from.push_back(offset);
        offset += thread_length[i];
    }
}
```

P.P.S. Each function except multithread sort was tested and works correctly

Comment: *Please, help to understand, what is wrong with this way of using threads, I`m absolutely confused.* -- I scanned your code for any synchronization going on.  You have none.  Multithreaded programming is much more than knowing how to create and start threads.  Also, you cannot enter the world of multithreaded programming using a single-threaded way of looking at the program.  It is totally different, with different issues.  For example, there is no guarantee that the threads will start in the loop in the order that you see them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, please, could you clarify about synchronization: there is loop where all threads are joined, is it wrong way? As I understand, function will not step to next line of code until all threads end their execution, that is synchronization.

Comment: This is a LOT of code for what should ultimately be threading into literally the *easiest* sorting algorithm in which to do it. I think your attempt would come together easier if you stopped tossing about vectors and used iterators (or pointers, but ideally iterators) instead. And fyi, if done correctly, a multi-threaded mergesort needs no synchronization (since nothing reads or writes any specific data concurrently, but you must be absolutely *certain* you live up to that requirement).

Comment: All your threads write to the same `buffer` concurrently with no synchronization.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, you are so right, thank you!
I just found it out: the problem was that in merge_arrays function writing to buffer started from 0 (but it must be = index of start of left subarray), so all threads always wrote to the beginning of buffer and took part in race condition.
Now I fixed that and sort works properly with variable count of threads.